# How to Spring JPA save String array data to database using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to Spring. Try to save following model to mysql using JPA

```
@Table(name = "PRODUCTORDER")
public class Order extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

@Length(min = 4, max = 30)
private String name;
@Length(min = 4, max = 50)
private String address;
@NotEmpty
private String[] items; // error for this

// only items setter and getter shown

public String[] getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(String[] items) {
    this.items = items;
}
}
```

I have a table in mySQL as :-

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTORDER ( 
       id int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
       name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
       address varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
       items varchar(50) not null, 
       PRIMARY KEY(id)
  ) 
  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I tried to save data I get this error:-

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException:    
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED   
\x00\x05ur...' for column 'items' at row 1; nested exception is   
javax.persistence.PersistenceException:org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:   
Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05ur...' for column 'items' at row 1
```

Comment: what is this Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05ur...'. Can you explain.

Comment: How would you store an array of strings into a single varchar column? You want two tables, and corresponding two entities, with a OneToMany association.

Comment: redefine your schema, use normalized tables then play with jpa.

Comment: This is how I initialise String[] items in my controller.     @ModelAttribute("items")
    public List<String> getItems() {
        return Arrays.asList("Porkkana", "Kaali", "Virtahepo");
    }